# Commit to Master greyed out

Tags: github-for-windows

I use Github for Windows and I have about ten repositories I regularly commit to from my local computer using the client. I'm used to everything working great. However, today, for one of my local repositories, I moved the .git file and folder to a new directory in order to relocate my local files  (which I've done successfully many times before), and then reopened Github to "locate" the new directory. Ever since I did this today, ALL of my repositories have their "Commit to Master" button greyed out in the Github client, and I can't commit anything anymore.

I even went so far as to completely uninstall Github, deleting the appdata and localappdata, and then reinstalled the client. This deleted all my repositories out of the client. When I then added one of my repositories back to the client, the "Commit to Master" button is still greyed out and can't be selected.

Anyone have any idea what the heck I did, or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's currently three conditions that need to be true for that button to be enabled.

1. The client isn't currently running a git operation on the selected repository
2. You've entered a title in the commit box
3. You've selected at least one file.

Assuming that you've satisfied the last two items the logical conclusion is that the client is currently running some type of long running operation or has initiated an operation that for some reason has run amok.

In order to get to the bottom of this I'd have to take a look at your log file. If you reach out to us through support@github.com and include a [log file](https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-the-github-for-windows-log) we can then update this question when we've had a look at that.

Comment: I have a situation that meets all three criteria - and the button is still disabled  http://superuser.com/questions/984886/new-repository-on-git-option-to-add-readme-md-apparently-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1355612_984886

Comment: I had it continue to do that to me until I put a .txt in the file extension.

Comment: i've also seen this happen when no email and username were configured

Comment: where do you configure the email and username?

Answer (score 3):

The Ghostery browser is [known](https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/issues/809) to cause this issue.

Disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the correct answer in my scenario.  Ghostery was blocking the button, as soon as I disabled Ghostery for Github the button was enabled.  Great find!

Comment: This was it! Github scripts seems to be blocked by Ghostery